# Does `div::after {content: ""; height: 100%}` only works when `div {position: absolute;}`?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute, pseudo-element

### Brief question:

Does `div::after {content: ""; display: block; height: 100%;}` only works when `div {position: absolute;}`?

Also does `height: 100%` refer to the height of related div tag?

### Explains:

I was trying to make a div have the ability to over scroll one page even if it reaches the bottom. So I used the following css:

```css
div::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Why ::after height: 100% only works when div has absolute positioning?

Is there any better solution? Because I don't like to add absolute positioning when it's not necessary.

#### Update 1:

I use Chrome 27

Comment: You could probably also use `position: relative;`

Comment: if you set an height to your div you don't need to specify a position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `height: 100%` property (or with any percentage value) [needs a *parent* element with some definition of actual `height` to work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property). That height definition can itself be a `height` property setting (but *not* a `min` or `max` version of that), or it can be (as in your case) by a `position: absolute` that you have also defined the height of by setting the `top` and `bottom` properties. Those are your two options besides using javascript (and javascript is only going to be able to help in reading and setting the height of the `div` so that the `::after` can pick it up, since javascript cannot affect the `::after` pseudo-element directly).

So the `::after` element has the `div` as its parent, and that is why something explicit needs to be setting the height of the `div` in order for the `::after` pseudo-element to pick up the actual height from it.

Comment: I found it interesting that if I do not declare `<!DOCTYPE html>` for my document, ::after content will automatically pick the height of window when height of div is not specified.